# Neo4j database - link or property?

Tags: properties, neo4j, nodes

I am new to neo4j and would appreciate some help on db design philosophy.

I have 1,000s of animals in my db, and each is one of around 10 species (cow, sheep, goat, cat, dog.....)

In a relational db I would have an animal table and a species table and each animal's species would be defined by a join between an animal id and a species id.

In neo4j the "obvious" approach is to have animals as nodes and species as one of their properties.   But that seems a backwards step as I face the classic problem of maintaining 1,000s of copies of species names with risk of spelling differences etc.

Alternatively, I have 1,000 animal nodes and 10 'species' nodes, with each animal pointing to a species with an IS_A relationship:

(daisy:Animal)-[IS_A]->(cow:Cow)

That 'feels' hideously clumsy. Almost every search will be for particular animal/species combinations.

What is the 'preferred' solution?

There are a bunch of similar decisions. eg every animal is either 'Alive' or 'Dead'.   Do I make that a property? Or do I point animals to one of two nodes called alive and dead?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

You could try using species as your labels, and nodes as animals of that species:

```
(daisy:Cow{name:'daisy'}), (daffy:Duck{name:'daffy'})
```

If you need to run queries across several species, treating them as animals, for example, you could multi-label your nodes so all :Cow, :Duck etc nodes are also labeled :Animal.

The disadvantage here is that node labels can't be dynamic in searches (or at least, you won't be able to take advantage of an indexed search like this).

So if a user could enter parameters `name:'daisy'` and `species:cow`, the fastest lookup (since you're dealing with a dynamic label) would be to have an index on `:Animal(name)`, and perform your match on this index, then filter on the species:

```
MATCH (animal:Animal)
WHERE animal.name = $name
AND $species in labels(animal)
RETURN animal
```

It's not much different than having a species as a field in :Animal nodes, except it's much easier to have visibility and reporting into labels in your graph (`call db.labels`), so misspellings should be much easier to both spot and correct.

In general, though, if your lookup tends to be `type + some property value`, that's a good case to model the type as a node label, and to create an index on the combination for a fast lookup.

As for boolean state, all options are available (node labels, :LifeState nodes with relationships to :Animal nodes, boolean isAlive or isDead properties). I'd personally prefer the boolean properties here.